# working with sequences of different length

Tags: r

a function I wrote extracts timestamps from a XML document.  Timestamps are coupled to events, which are repeated elements of the series element.

series elements have a variable amount of events, so my function returns a data.frame (if the series have the same length).  in general it returns a more generic list and I want it to work with matrices as well.  I was pointed out (Thanks Eduardo) that 'list' is the generic type, but I still have trouble with functions that work on generic lists but not with more specific types, like data.frame or matrix.

what I need to do with the data at the moment is to see what is the most common distance between timestamps (I expect it to appear (much) more often than 50% of the times), I have written and rewritten a function doing this:

```
R> mostCommonStep( list(a=cumsum(c(1,3,3,2,3,3,4,3,2,3,3)), b=cumsum(c(2,3,2,3))) )
[1] 3
R> mostCommonStep( data.frame(a=c(2,4,6,8,12,14,18), b=c(12,14,16,18,22,24,28)) )
[1] 2
R> mostCommonStep( matrix(c(2,4,6,8,12,14,18, 12,14,16,18,22,24,28), 7, 2) )
[1] 2
```

but I would like to see a more "R" conformant version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would settle with this one (works if the most common step really occurs more often than in 50% of the cases).

```
mostCommonStep <- function(L) {
  ## returns the value of the most common difference between
  ## subsequent elements.

  ## takes into account only forward steps, all negative steps are
  ## discarded.  works with list, data.frame, matrix.
  L <- diff(unlist(sapply(as.list(L), as.numeric)))
  as.numeric(quantile(L[L>0], 0.5))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

data frames are lists. Suppose the distance between time stamps is in the vector "x" in list/data.frame y. you could do `sort(-table(y[["x"]]))[1]` to get the mode.

Comment: my data contains only timestamps.  that is: all columns contain timestamps and I want to examine all columns.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to approach this is probably to use an irregular time series object (see [the time series view on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html)).  You have several good options (e.g. timeSeries, its, fts, xts), but the most popular of these is [the **zoo** package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html).  You can create a time series like so:

```
library(zoo)
x.Date <- as.Date("2003-02-01") + c(1, 3, 7, 9, 14) - 1
x <- zoo(rnorm(5), x.Date)
```

Then, to see the difference in time between each event, you can just use the diff function to create a `difftime` object:

```
> diff(index(x))
Time differences in days
[1] 2 4 2 5
```

You can analyze these time difference just like you would any other variable, for instance:

```
> summary(diff(index(x)))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   2.00    2.00    3.00    3.25    4.25    5.00
```

Similarly, to find the most common time difference, you can use any other standard approach such as `table()`:

```
> table(diff(index(x)))
2 4 5 
2 1 1
```

Comment: I'm afraid my problem is that I am not (yet) confident with the "any other case" and with the "other standard approach[es]".